# Microsoft Edge disappeared

Tags: windows, java, avast

I had a message from Avast to delete Java 6 and update. I did that and then Microsoft Edge disappeared. Also after deleting 6 I found out that later versions would not work with Edge. Then after I restarted computer the ME disappeared.

I tried to restore computer.  But there was no Restore point. Have since updated to 8 Java and updated my Avast.  Still no microsoft edge.
I did this Follow the steps below to do an SFC Scan.

1. Press Windows Key and type “cmd”.
   Right-Click on the Command Prompt and select Run as Administrator.
2. Type “sfc /scannow” and hit Enter.
3. Exit Command Prompt.
   No faults found.  Have  found the icon and made a shortcut but still will not open at all .  What else can I do.  Thanks.

Comment: If you type `Edge` in the search box of the start menu, does *anything* come up? Sometimes if the package is corrupted a strange string will come up at least.

Comment: MS Edge does not work with any version of Java, it has Java built in, and the version it has built in isn't Java 6.  So your removal of Java 6 which is insecure and should have been removed years ago, isn't the reason MS Edge is now missing, something else is going on.  MS Edge has the current version of Java, which would be Java 8, not Java 6.